# Adding Custom Validation on user Model Go

Tags: go, validation

I have been trying to validate user registration, but I am getting so many errors. I want to validate phone to match a certain format and password to have both letter, a special character and a number.

Here is my code

```
package models

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"
)

type User struct {
    UserId    primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id"`
    F_name    *string            `json:"f_name" validate:"required"`
    L_name    *string            `json:"l_name" validate:"required"`
    Username  *string            `json:"username"`
    Phone     *string            `json:"phone" validate:"required,phone"`
    Email     *string            `json:"email" validate:"required,email"`
    Pronoun   *string            `json:"pronoun" validate:"required,eq=he_him|eq=she_her|eq=them_they"`
    Password  *string            `json:"password" validate:"required,min=8,containsLetter,containsSpecialChar"`
    Role      *string            `json:"role" validate:"required,eq=customer"`
    Verified  *bool              `json:"verified"`
    Active    *bool              `json:"active"`
    Avatar    *string            `json:"avatar" validate:"required"`
    Qrcode    *string            `json:"qrcode"`
    CreatedAt time.Time          `json:"createdAt"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time          `json:"updatedAt"`
}

func ValidateUser(user *User) error {
    validate := validator.New()
    validate.RegisterValidation("containsLetter", func(fl validator.FieldLevel) bool {
        return strings.ContainsAny(fl.Field().String(), "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
    })
    validate.RegisterValidation("containsSpecialChar", func(fl validator.FieldLevel) bool {
        re := regexp.MustCompile(`[!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+\-\=\[\]\{\}\|\;\:\,\.\/\<\>\?\\]`)
        return re.MatchString(fl.Field().String())
    })
    validate.RegisterValidation("phone", func(fl validator.FieldLevel) bool {
        re := regexp.MustCompile(`^\+\d{1,3}\-\d{9,10}$`)
        return re.MatchString(fl.Field().String())
    })
    if user.Verified == nil {
        user.Verified = new(bool)
        *user.Verified = false
    }
    if user.Active == nil {
        user.Active = new(bool)
        *user.Active = true
    }
    if err := validate.Struct(user); err != nil {
        var errMessages []string
        for _, err := range err.(validator.ValidationErrors) {
            errMessages = append(errMessages, fmt.Sprintf("field %s failed validation: %s", err.Field(), err.Tag()))
        }
        return errors.New(strings.Join(errMessages, ", "))
    }
    return nil
}
```

What would wrong with my code. I am getting the following errors

> 2023/03/24 19:42:13 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:52498: Undefined
> validation function 'phone' on field 'Phone'

Somebody please help

Comment: I am trying to build a custom one

Answer (score 0):

there is no `phone` tag but we do have `e164` https://github.com/go-playground/validator#format

you can check if it fits your requirements, otherwise having your custom validator is also a good option.